# "localhost refused to connect" vscode html

Tags: html, css, macos, visual-studio-code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <button>Hello</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Running this code from VSCode on my M1 Air yields either this:

[image: error page]

..or a completely blank page.

What am I doing wrong? Was working, but then I accidentally clicked "run" on a .css file instead of my .html file, and it broke.

Comment: what do you mean by running? how are you serving this file?

Comment: by "running", I mean pressing the "Run" button in VSCode. pretty sure it just locally hosts a server to put the html code on but I rly have no idea. I just know that usually I press run and a webpage is created from my HTML code lmao

Answer (score 0):

You can just open your `.html` file by double-clicking on it from your file browser.

Or if you want to serve it locally, you can use an extension like [Live server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer). And then from your Editor, you can click on "Go Live"

[image: click on go live]

Then this would show that your local server is running on a port like here it's `5500`

[image: running on port 5500]

Then the extension should open a new tab in your browser to `http://127.0.0.1:5500/FILENAME.html`.

If you don't want to use this VS Code extension, you can try other alternatives like [browsersync](https://browsersync.io/).